# If $g$ has finite order $n$ show that $n$ is the least number such that $g^n$ is the neutral element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The order of the element $g$ is the size (cardinality) of the group $\langle g \rangle$. If $g$ has finite order $n$ show that $n$ is the least number such that $g^n$ is the neutral element.

I can see that there are multiple m such that g^m=g^n=e but I don't know how to go about showing that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: the trick is to understand the question and the concepts involved... Which can be difficult enough unless you already do!

Comment: just practice questions

Comment: @String Indeed. Those concepts are then explained in the book, and the exercises are there for you to check if you have understood said concepts. Thus, if you need to ask about an exercise, you need to ask about something specific or the answer will not help you understand the concepts.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I think you're being a tad harsh. Even if its a two-line proof that is obvious after you see it, that doesn't necessarily make the problem trivial. Indeed, even if you can see why it must be true, writing a coherent argument involving cardinality can sometimes be tricky.

Comment: @user18921 I didn't say it was trivial. I said this is the sort of exercise meant to test if you have understood the concepts. If you are unable to solve it yourself, just getting a full solution is unlikely to be as helpful as a good hint. But a good hint requires more information about what part makes you stuck.

Comment: Must solve practice questions $\to$ asks question on MSE with no indication about the problematic step $\to$ receives a full bolts-on solution $\to$ did not practice the subject one iota.

Comment: @Did I do apologise but I had lecture then work then slept so have had little time to check back here and add anything more to my question.
I basically got as far as the answer below, but in less detail and I can't see any further as how to prove that n must be smaller than m.

Comment: No problem about that.